# EF 6 include() not solving N + 1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

I've got a class similar to

```
 public class Entity
 {
    virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
 }
```

In the repository I do

```
  return Context.Entities
                .Include(x => x.Contacts)
                .Include(x => x.PhoneNumbers)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .toList();
```

EFProf still shows Select N + 1?? I thought include was supposed to handle this?

[image]

EDIT: It seems the issue is occuring during serialization? I'm just trying to return a paged list of objects via a Web API.
[image]

Comment: How are you handling this data in the controller?

Comment: How does your DbContext configuration look like? Did you set EnableLazyLoading to false?

Comment: added an answer.. I'm not sure if this whole question could help someone else or just needs to die...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the related entities has lazily loaded relationships.

One of the properties on my original models (Contact) had a list of phone numbers to itself. So although the Contacts were not lazily evaluated, each Contact had it's own phone numbers lazy loaded due to being virtual and not explicitly included.

Comment: I think if you give a better explanation of why lazy loading happened here that would be useful.

Comment: just noticed this - It happened because I was serializing the entities directly to JSON, which triggered the evaluation of those lazily loaded relationships during the object graph traversal that serialization requires